# scanf сохроняет в себя лишнее значение "\n" в C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char scan;
    while (true)
    {
        printf(">>");
        scanf_s("%c", &scan);
        if (scan == 'c') {
            printf("\nC\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Во время первой итерации ввожу символ к примеру "c" и жму Enter чтобы завершить ввод
На второй итерации выполняет `printf(">>");` , но `scanf_s("%c", &scan);` не выполняется вместо этого переменная scan принимает значение `\n` возможно как-то сохраняет перенос строки из прошлого ввода.

Как это исправить и почему так происходит?

Ps:
Бесконечный цикл был задуман

Comment: Когда вы вводите символ `c` и нажимаете Enter, во входной поток добавляются два символа: символ `c` и символ перевода строки `\n`. `scanf_s` считывает символ `c`, но во входном потоке всё ещё находится символ `\n`, который будет считан `scanf_s` на следующей итерации. Либо считывайте символ перевода строки отдельно, либо замените `"%c"` на `" %c"`, тогда `scanf_s` будет игнорировать пробельные символы.

Comment: Спасибо,работает

Comment: @wololo, ответы - в ответы.

Comment: Этот дубликат уже в тысячный раз здесь...